# Blank Space above the header-Blogger

Tags: html, blogs

I have this problem with the blank space above the header: http://prntscr.com/1edij7.I tried to edit "`margin-top`" and stuff like that but it wouldn't work. Please..I need some answers..I tried everything on Google.

I have already tried to edit these settings:

```
#outer-wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal 100% Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Template code: http://justpaste.it/chotemplate

Answer (score 0):

Set your html and body margin/padding to 0px.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `div` with the `header` id. It's the cause of that space. In addition to your current settings for this id, you can try with this:

```
#header {
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Do you think that you can look for the error in the template code: http://justpaste.it/chotemplate ? Thank you!

Comment: I can see the "header" element defined in your link, something like `#header {0;color: #006699;background: #fff;}` (but in various lines). Just put the float attribute inside, so you gets `#header {0; color: #006699; background: #fff; float: left;}` and see how it works. Also you can try it modifying the style using firebug or a similar tool.

Comment: You're welcome ;) (but don't forget to check this as the correct answer, hehe).